# Prove that $A\cap B\subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am unsure if I got it right, I proved it as follows:

$$A\cap B \longleftrightarrow x\in A \text{ and } x\in B \text{ is true }\forall x\in A \longleftrightarrow \subseteq A$$

Althought I kind of doubt the last part about it being true for all $x\in A$. Am I missing something?

I apologize in advance if this post is a duplicate.

Comment: i did not understand anything in the last part.Can you clarify your question a little bit clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition: $x\in A\cap B$ if and only if $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.

If it is false that $A\cap B \subseteq A$, then $\exists x\in A\cap B: x \notin A$. But this contradicts the definition. So, it must be that $A\cap B \subseteq A$.

Comment: Perfect example of a proof by contradiction where it is not necessary or doesn't simplify anything at all!

Comment: I didn't want to downvote because it is not wrong, but it is still bad practise I think.

Answer (score 1):

You are done after the first $\longleftrightarrow$ . This means that $x \in A \cap B \implies x \in A$, which satisfies the result by the definition of a subset.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $C \subseteq A$ iff $x \in C \implies x \in A$.

Apply this to $C = A \cap B$:

$x \in A \cap B \implies x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \implies x \in A$

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch of the proof.** We want to prove that one set is a subset of other set. Recall the definition of a subset.

> **Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be any sets. We say that $A$ is a ***subset*** of $B$, and we write $A \subseteq B,$ if every element of $A$ is, also, an element of $B,$ i.e.,
> $$(\forall x) x \in A \implies x \in B$$

Hence, to prove that $A \cap B \subseteq A$ we must prove the above implication, i.e., prove that for an arbitrary objet c we have that $c \in A \cap B \implies c \in A.$

---

***Proof.*** Let $x$ be an arbitrary object. Suppose that $x \in A \cap B.$ By definition of set intersection, we have that $x \in A$ and $x \in B.$ In particular, we have that $x \in A.$ Hence, by definition of subset, we conclude that $A \cap B \subseteq A.$ $\square$

---

**Remark.** Also, (and maybe to get some intuitive sense), note that if you have the propositions $p$ and $q$ and you know that $p \wedge q$ is true, what can you say about each $p$ and $q?$

They have to be both true (by definition of conjunction). Suppose that (at least) one of them is false. Without loss of generality, suppose that $p$ is the one which if false. Hence, $p \wedge q$ would be false, which is an absurd because it contradict the fact that $p \wedge q$ is true. The absurd came from assuming that (at least) one of them is false. Hence, both $p$ and $q$ must be true.

From this discussion, observe that $x \in A cap B$ is logically equivalent to $x \in A \wedge x \in B.$ Hence, if this proposition is true, then both $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ are true. Therefore, $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B.$